# How to check the same values between 2 table (MSAccess)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlVaM.png)

I think I have to  use loop function, but I don't know how to write that (Thank you)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * From TableName
Where columnName ==(
SELECT TableName from AnotherTableName
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM BB
 WHERE CODE NOT IN 
 (SELECT AA.code FROM AA)
```